# Flask extensions & its configuration

Tags: python, flask

I have some trouble finding a pythonic way to run a Flask app with extensions' config parameters.

Here's my `myapp/__init__.py`, which initializes the flask app and its extensions:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.redis import Redis

app = Flask(__name__)

manager = Manager(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
redis = Redis(app)
```

I decided to store app's configuration in separate files for debugging and deployment and loading them with `Flask.config.from_pyfile`.

Configuration file has several options, including:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:////tmp/test.db"
REDIS_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_DB = 0
```

I use Flask-Script to run the server:

```
from myapp import app, manager

@manager.command
def debug():
    app.config.from_pyfile("debug.cfg")
    app.run()
```

While SQLAlchemy works OK (creating an SQLite database at the `/tmp/test.db`), I have yet to run Redis instance because it seems to try hard and find `REDIS_HOST` in `app.config` before it was even loaded from the config file.

Is there any way to bypass it without having to hardcode the default settings before config was imported from file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you pass in `app` to the `Redis()` constructor you need to have the configuration loaded.

Postpone passing in `app`, call `redis.init_app(app)` after loading the configuration:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

manager = Manager(app)
db = SQLAlchemy()
redis = Redis()

def attach_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app)
    redis.init_app(app)
```

then when configuration has loaded:

```
from myapp import app, manager, attach_extensions

@manager.command
def debug():
    app.config.from_pyfile("debug.cfg")
    attach_extensions(app)
    app.run()
```

Comment: Oh. Didn't know about `init_app`. Thanks a lot!